# Regex Replace to Remove Spaces and Change Comma to Period

Tags: regex

I have the following values:

```
10 000,00
 10 000,00
750,00
 750,00
1 000 000,00
 1 000 000,00
```

and need the following results:

```
10000.00
10000.00
750.00
750.00
1000000.00
1000000.00
```

I've managed to do this in 2 steps; first by replacing `,` with `.` and then by regex replacing `[^0-9.]` with nothing.

How can I achieve this in 1 regex replace step?

Comment: The duplicate numbers (SO changed my formatting): One has a space in front, one does not.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do in one regex. Why is it important to do it in one step?

Comment: It is possible in some tools/some regex methods. What are you using?

Comment: I'm using an in-house program written in C#.  It isn't absolutely necessary to do in 1 step.  I'm just trying to improve my regex.  The in-house program scans PDFs and certain European fields (ie. price with thousand separator of space) must be formatted NA style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't think of any generic approach that would be useful in every situation, but there *is* a regex that accomplishes what you want: `( ?(\d+))?( ?(\d+))?( ?(\d+)),`

```js
let string = `10 000,00
 10 000,00
750,00
 750,00
1 000 000,00
 1 000 000,00
 1,00
10,00`;
 
let result = string.replace(/( ?(\d+))?( ?(\d+))?( ?(\d+)),/g, '$2$4$6.');

console.log(result);
```

The explanation is pretty simple (I'll only explain the last part):

```
(        # Capturing group 
   ?     # Space (one or zero)
  (      # Nested capturing group
    \d+  # One or more digits
  )
)
,        # Captures a comma
```

The pattern repeats itself for three times because the maximum value in the sample string is at 10<sup>3</sup>. It won't capture higher order values, for that you'd need to repeat the pattern `( ?(\d+))?` according to your needs (Note the `?` at the end to make the pattern optional, allowing you to keep matching smaller values).

For the replacement, you'd select only the inner capturing groups, which in this case are `$2`, `$4` and `$6`, but if the pattern grows up you'd keep going to `$8`, `$10` and over. Then you insert a dot at the end of the replacement: `$2$4$6.` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language you're using.

But In JS this can be achieved with the callback function available in replace method.

```js
let str = `10 000,00
 10 000,00
750,00
 750,00
1 000 000,00
 1 000 000,00`
 
let op = str.replace(/( +)|(,)/g, function(match,g1,g2){
  if(g1 && g1.length){
    return ''
  } else {
    return '.'
  }
})

console.log(op)
```