# How can I replace more than one string with another using just one Regex or do I have to use multiple Regex and temp strings?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a variable being given a value like this:

```
vm.WordType = phrase.WordType;
```

where the value of phrase.WordType can be something like this:

```
"Godan verb with ru ending, Transitive Verb"
```

and I would like to change it to

```
"Godan v with ru end, Transitive v"
```

I can use Regex to for example replace verb with v but is there a way that I can use Regex to do more replacements, such as replace "ending" with "end" or do I have to somehow string together multiple Regex and use temp variables?

```
vm.WordType = Regex.Replace(phrase.WordType, "verb", "v", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: in JS you can use groupings and callback function in replace, i think you can do same sort of thing in c# too. by using a function instead of `v`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You can read this answer to understand what i am talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/54578357/9624435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course just call `Regex.Replace` 2 times - the first time replacing "verb", the second time replacing "ending".

If you don't like that, you could do it in one single regex like this:

```
Regex.Replace("Godan verb with ru ending, Transitive Verb", "(v)erb|(end)ing", "$1$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The regex I used here is:

```
(v)erb|(end)ing
```

It matches either "verb" and puts "v" into group 1, or it matches "ending" and puts "end" into group 2.

The replacement is `$1$2`, which means group 1 and group 2.

Let's say you also want to replace "transitive" with "trans", you could easily change the regex to:

```
(v)erb|(end)ing|(trans)itive
```

and the replacement to all three groups:

```
$1$2$3
```

Note that this approach will preserve case, so "Verb" becomes "V" and "verb" becomes "v". If this is undesirable, you can pass in a `MatchEvaluator` to convert them to lowercase:

```
Regex.Replace(
            "Godan verb with ru ending, Transitive Verb", 
            "(v)erb|(end)ing",
            x => string.Join("", x.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(y => y.Value)).ToLowerInvariant(),
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```